# Adding 'throws' on an extended class?

Tags: java, extends, throws

I'm making a simple application with the Socket API, but have run into a small issue that I haven't found the answer for.

The application is supposed to be multi-threaded, so that the main method starts both the server and client threads.

```
public class UDPClientServer1 extends Thread
```

However, since the the Socket classes need to throw some specific exceptions, I must also do this:

```
public void runClient() throws SocketException, UnknownHostException, IOException
```

and similarly for the runServer() method.

Not that there's anything wrong with that, but is there a more elegant solution? Something along the lines of :

```
public class UDPClientServer1 extends Thread, throws Exception
```

Comment: `throws` goes at method level. The most elegant solution would be not throwing an `Exception` at all.

Comment: How would that work, though? If I don't throw anything then there's a complaint about an unreported SocketException and/or IOException. Do you mean a simple try/catch?

Comment: Yes, and using a logger to handle and report the `Exception`s. Of course, not all the methods should have a big `try-catch` statement at the beginning and end respectively i.e. `public void aMethod(...) { try { ... } catch(Exception e) { ... } }`, otherwise there could be a problem in your design.

Comment: catching an exception and handling is different than throwing

Comment: Note that you can have a presentation component that will handle any exception and display it accordingly and you just rethrow all the `Exception`s and let this presentation component handle them, but that entirely depends on your application design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you may want to wrap the exception that your throw, either converting it to a `RuntimeException` if the error is unrecoverable, or at least a more appropriate / encapsulated exception.

E.g.

```
public void runClient throws ClientException
{
    try
    {
        // do something
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.error("Exception encountered in client",e);
        throw new ClientException("Unrecoverable client exception encountered",e);
        // or: throw new RuntimeException("Unrecoverable client exception",e);
    }
}
```

`ClientException` in the above is your own exception that you would need to create.  Its purpose is to encapsulate the implementation details of corresponding exceptions from any calling code.

Using a `RuntimeException`, however, may be more appropriate if there is no reasonable way for the calling code to respond to the exception.  When throwing a RuntimeException you do not have to declare it in the method signature and calling code does not need to explicitly handle it (although it should be handled at some point).